# spacing problem for more than three algorithms in one page

Tags: spacing, algorithms, algorithmic

I use algorithm and algpseudocode package. Problem is, when I tried to start the fourth procedure\function, the fourth one starts in the middle of the next page instead of right below to  the third one, no matter how much the space left in the first page.

I then tried to put more procedures. It appears that extra procedures will auto distribute evenly in the second page. (Two extra will be arranged to evenly divide the second page, etc.)

This is really troublesome. Could anyone tell me how to let the fourth algorithm display below the third just like the third below the second and avoid the auto-arrangement problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is massively underspecified so we'll have to guess, but assuming you are making each algorithm a separate float then it will be governed by the float parameters. These are set by the class (which you haven't said which you are using) but in article the main ones are

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
```

so in particular you can not have more than three floats on a page unless you increase `totalnumber` or use the `[!]` option to ignore the parameters.

MWE added so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{ABC}{S}
\If {A}
    \State A
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you tell me how to use the [!] option? The way I change totalnumber is add \setcounter{totalnumber}{3}, and change the 3. Then how to add [!] then? Thank you!

Comment: @Peter I meant use `[!...]` on the environment as in the code I added after you provided a MWE